# Two string compare after grep

Tags: linux, grep, csh

I got the following line

```
2020-10-17 14:55:39,586 INFO  [http-bio-exec-60] [] [D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326.server.host.com.:9991] [some.package.Class] TEST_STRING - RSI: 506B48ECADC4BE0CEBF7C7D33D036B67.server.host.com.:9991
```

I do grep "D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326" and got the line above. Is there a way to run a command after grep to check if D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326 and 506B48ECADC4BE0CEBF7C7D33D036B67 are equal?

Thanks.

Comment: Pipe the output of grep into Perl one-liner that splits on \W+ (non-word characters) and compares the fields after splitting.

Comment: `if [ $( grep -o D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326 inputFile) = "D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326" ] ; then echo found str in inputFile ; echo echo no match" ; fi` (maybe you need `-eq` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you already know the first pattern:

```
PATTERN=D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326
grep "\[$PATTERN.*RSI: $PATTERN" input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

*I got the following line*, that's not a good way to start here:

Your line contains quite some information, and as mentioned in the comments, you might parse it using Perl or awk or any other tool, but I would advise otherwise: how do you get this line (I guess it's an output of some process)? You might ask the author of that other process to alter the output in such a way that it's easier for you do parse it and do the comparison you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe `grep` output into this Perl one-liner, which splits the line on non-word characters and prints it if fields 13 and 23 are identical as strings:

```
echo '2020-10-17 14:55:39,586 INFO  [http-bio-exec-60] [] [D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326.server.host.com.:9991] [some.package.Class] TEST_STRING - RSI: 506B48ECADC4BE0CEBF7C7D33D036B67.server.host.com.:9991' | \
  grep 'D88E13F571A51598613FAA078A215326' | \
  perl -F'/\W+/' -lane 'print if $F[12] eq $F[22];'
```